# error in serialization javascript from json to text

Tags: javascript

i have an error in serialisation i need someone to fix it and that 's code controller

```
   public string Getrowselec(string id)
        {
    GestionprojetEntities ddb = new GestionprojetEntities();
                Ressourcehumaine _ressource = new Ressourcehumaine();
                _ressource = ddb.Ressourcehumaine.Find(Convert.ToInt32(id));


                int id_ressource = int.Parse(id);
                var query = (from u in ddb.Ressourcehumaine
                             where (u.Id == id_ressource)
                             select new
                             {
                                 id = u.Id,
                                 nom = u.Nom,
                                 prixrevient = u.Prixrevient,
                                 prixvente = u.Prixvente,
                                 coutdirect = u.Coutdirect,
                             });

                string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
 return javascriptJson;
```

and this is my code in twig code javascript:

```
 function Getrows(s, e) {
        debugger;
        var id = e.visibleIndex;
        var key = s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);
        idProduit = key;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Projet/Getrowsselec?id=" + key,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                $("#nomclient_I").val(jsonObject[0]['nom']);
                $("#codeclient_I").val(jsonObject[0]['id']);

            }
        })
}
```

can someone help me fix this issue the error in serialisation i think some error in serialisation 
from json to text

Comment: `jsonObject`? Why `jsonObject`? Where does this variable name come from? You're receiving `response`, not `jsonObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you need to add this to your response ajax try it and tell me if it work or not

```
success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
                $("#nomclient_I").val(jsonObject[0]['nom']);
                $("#codeclient_I").val(jsonObject[0]['id']);

            }
```